# spark Streaming operate on foreach group

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a stream of data comes from various sources. In each source, there are number of sensors available. A simplified input DStream data format given below,

### Source  |  Sensor  |  Value

A      |  SType1  |  On

A      |  SType2  |  Off

A      |  SType1  |  On

B      |  SType3  |  Off

B      |  SType2  |  Off

B      |  SType1  |  On

Please note, data have additional columns as well in the real scenario and later processing used all those columns

As of now, all DStream window operations are working on this without any issues. But I want to do my DStream operations on each "`Source`" separately. Meaning, on Source A, I want to do a set of operations. The same set will be repeated in Source B and other sources as well like below.. (Not sure whether I am conveying this correctly..)

--foreachSource
     --On each window
     --foreachRDD
      -- Do Operation

> My operation is custom requirement..  I want to find "`whether any
>   Sensor+value subsequence exists`" under a specific source.
>   For Eg.. in the above example..
>
> > My reference sub sequence = **Stype1+On & Stype2+Off**  and this exists
> >     only with Source `"A"`
>
> To do my sub sequence finding operation, I have written a function
>   under foreachRDD and it works fine. But iterating through each source 
>   inside that function is may not be efficient

Ideally, I think above foreachSource(func) should give different Dstream based on each source. In that way I can make use of all available DStream APIs (windowing etc..) in the "`func`" on each source.

Some of my research below.

I did some goggling and tried some methods using `Group by` / `join` etc. But without success.
Below link shows how to maintain a session between various Stream inputs -- Thinking this can be tweaked

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/11/how-to-do-near-real-time-sessionization-with-spark-streaming-and-apache-hadoop/

[PySpark - Combining Session Data without Explicit Session Key / Iterating over All Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880370/pyspark-combining-session-data-without-explicit-session-key-iterating-over-a?rq=1)
Is anyway to achieve this?..

My language of choice is python...

Comment: Are you expecting each window to add to aggregated values you've previously computed? In other words windowNResults = window1Results + window2Results etc.

Comment: Thanks @Bryce for asking...  I am not looking to persist states between windows.. I think that can be achieved using UpdateStateByKey. I have edited my question to explain my operation on each window in detail. I am not quite sure whether that kind of a construct exists or not..